# React router in react stepzilla

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-stepzilla

I am using [react stepzilla](https://github.com/newbreedofgeek/react-stepzilla) to create a step wizzard for my forms. Now, I need to show the URL path for each step in the browser. By default stepzilla does not show the URL paths.

Is it possible to include React router and include the stepzilla component in the routes?

Here is my component that defined the steps and render the react stepzilla component:

```js
const StepNavigation = (props) => {
  const steps =
      [
        { name: '1', component: <Intro {...props} /> },
        { name: '2', component: <UserForm {...props} /> },
        { name: '3', component: <Finish {...this.props} /> },
      ];

  return (
    <div className="stepNavigation">
      <StepZilla
        steps={steps}
        preventEnterSubmission
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default StepNavigation;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import StepZilla from "react-stepzilla";

const Step = ({ name }) => {
  return <h1>Step:{name}</h1>;
};

const steps = [
  { name: "Step1", component: <Step name="One" /> },
  { name: "Step2", component: <Step name="Two" /> }
];

function App({ history }) {
  const handleChange = step => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/",
      search: `?step=${step}`
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StepZilla steps={steps} onStepChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

const RoutedApp = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" render={App} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<RoutedApp />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmrypxlv57).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Your solution looks great, I will try to implement it in my project.

Comment: Sure thing! If it works for you, feel free to mark it as the answer :)